# Ordering the data based on relation beetwen two of them

Tags: algorithm

The idea is simple, I have like 2000 rows of data about the matches between teams. I want to order the teams by strength strange comparing to each other based on results of the matches they had in the past.

Lets say here is the matches that already happened:

```
1 vs 2 => 2 Won
2 vs 1 => 2 Won
3 vs 1 => 1 Won
4 vs 3 => 3 Won
5 vs 3 => 5 Won
1 vs 5 => 5 Won
```

Now based on this information I want to order the teams. Any idea or known algorithm for this? The result should be something like:

```
1st: Team 2
2nd: Team 5
3rd: Team 1
4th: Team 3
5th: Team 4
```

ofc the data here is very limited and simple.

**Data:**
Data contains all the games in last year from all the leagues. Two team may have no game, or one or more game with each other. There is also a possibility for cycles. Like A vs B => B, B vs C => C and C vs A => A as these are real world data. What I want is a way to sort the data and guess their strength related to each other (Not to the games. Like adding or removing score based on their win) and what is important for me is the end result. So if this mean removing some matches from the equation to calculate the result better, I am ok with it.

**Accuracy Note:**
Based on the information, there is no indication if team 2 is better than team 5 or vice versa. So it would be great if we can find a way to calculate a number as the weight of position or something like that.

Comment: where does this 50% and 100% accuracy came from?

Comment: @Lrrr, based on the information, there is no indication if team 2 is better than team 5 or vice versa. So I thought the accuracy of the place is 50%. Tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: please make this kind of things clear in your question, we cant read your mind

Comment: also is there always a winner?

Comment: @Lrrr, I dont actually care about that.

Comment: well what do you do in this situation: A won against B, B won against C and C won against A - who is first? As long as you don't get you requirements figured out (what is that vague thing about accuracy - can you formalize that?) we can only guess with you...

Comment: obviously you want to model some sports league ranking-table - I honestly don't understand why you don't use just that (pick your favorite league from the real world and model your ranking after them)

Comment: Ok lets forget the accuracy part from the equation. I will edit the question to remove it as well. Now what? I know that there will be problems when there is a cycle in the data. I know it before asking. This is not actually a condition or requirement. This is a part of the actual question. I am here to ask if you know a way to sort this data and have any idea about solving data integrity issues. If it was a league, I had no need to ask about sorting. The data I have is more like all the games on all the leagues in the last year. One team may and may not have a game with an other team.

Comment: there just will be no way to make any meaningful ordering then - the best I can come up with is to score it as a draw when two teams did not play against each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers assume there is a proper order (and no "cycles") in the winners pairs.

Seems to me like you are looking for a [**topological sort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) in a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). This can be solved in linear time.

The vertices are the teams, and the edges are the relations of who won for each pair.

Regarding the accuracy: that could be a bit complicated, but one (partial) approach to handle it could be:

During the topological sort, when you have `k` choices at some point, chose one at random, and give all possibilities probability `1/k`.

The probability issue is just  a raw tryout, you will need to tweak it better to get exactly what you wanted to handle all cases properly.

Comment: Sounds like the right tool. Yet I cant be sure that there is no cycles in the data. So I need to find a way to remove them before trying to sort using this algorithm.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati how you want to remove cycles in your data?!

Comment: @Lrrr, I never said that I know a way :) but I think if I can find them, I may be able to break the chain by removing the oldest match. Cant I?

Comment: yeah this will be a really fair system - the *fans* will be pleased ;)

Comment: @SoroushFalahati we dont know your requirements, we dont know your conditions, we dont know what you could or couldnt do with your data! please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Carsten, the oldest match is actually the inaccurate one (comparing to others). And since fans wont be able to see the algorithm, I am safe xD

Comment: @SoroushFalahati so when they don't see it just use a RNG :P

Comment: @Lrrr, sry if the question wasn't clear enough and I appreciate that you are trying to help me with this issue. Yet the reason I am here is to try to help you guys to understand the problem and update the question if I missed anything. Sometimes describing a problem is not as easy as reading a help center page ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should have a dictionary/lookup for team->points. Whenever a team wins add a point. If it loses subtract one point.

After you did this for all games (two operations per game) you may sort this lookup with "points" as the sort key.

If two teams have the same number of points you may indicate this like (same rank as ...)

There is no such thing as "accuracy". A team is better as another or has the same rank.

If the game produces more detailed results like "number of goals goals" you may create a second ranking based on "goal difference" using a very similar approach.

Comment: This was my idea at first as well. Yet I found that using this method I dont actually know if a team is better than the other one. I just know if a team performed better than an other one. So a weaker team can have a higher place on list.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati what does *weaker*  and *stronger* mean anyway? As I tried to show you in my comment above you will have difficulties making this into an order so sorting will be a problem as well

Comment: You could try different weightings, e.g. +2 for win, -1 for loss, or +1 for win and no deductions for loss, and see what makes the most sense.